# Ubuntu 13.04 does not detect HDMI

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi, external-monitor

I have just upgraded my Dell M1330 with Intel GM965 graphics from 12.04 to 13.04 (fresh install).

Now when I plug in an external monitor on HDMI, nothing happens. It seems that HDMI is only detected on boot and when I open screen settings, or run xrandr in a terminal.
VGA works, although a bit slow sometimes.

I would report this as a bug, if I wasn't so unsure what the actual reason for the problem actually is.

Can anyone please help me so my computer detects HDMI again ike on 12.04 (where it worked flawlesly)?

Comment: lspci output available at: http://pastebin.com/XU9WCevA

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install bumblebee?  I think first you need to type in your terminal  " lspci " and see what kind of VGA are connected in your laptop, after you should see if the bumblebee can help you.

Comment: I know bumblebee wont help. I only have a GM965 and no nVidia.